# Initial state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I need download data from server before render() and cover it with HTML.I have error  ***this.state.news is undefinded*** . I tried examples with *getInitialState* and *componentWillMount*, but it isn't working.

```
import { Component } from 'react'

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import $ from 'jquery'

export default class News extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { news: []};
}

componentWillMount() {
    const setState = this.setState;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "localhost/news",
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
            setState(() => data);
        },
    });
}

render(){
    let news = this.state.news;
    return(
        news.map(function(n, i){
            return <div class="news-block">
                <Link to={`/news/post/${n.id}`}><h5>{n.theme}</h5></Link>
                <small>
                    <Link to={`/user/${n.author}`}>
                        {n.author}
                    </Link>, {n.date_of_create}
                </small>
                <p>{n.about}</p>
            </div>;
        })
    );
}
}
```

Example of json from ajax request:

```
 {
  "news": [
    {
      "id": "35268",
      "theme": "The,e",
      "author": "alex",
      "date_of_create": "2000-01-01 00:00:54",
      "public": "0",
      "about": "sometjing",
      "source": "some news"
    }
   ]
   }
```

Comment: please ask in english, or use https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your have several problems with that code.

The first one is that you are acting as you were getting the data in a sync way while you are working with async data.

The other one is that you are accessing the attribute `news' on your state, but it's not assigned never.

You should try with something like this:

```
import { Component } from 'react'

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import $ from 'jquery'

export default class News extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.getNews = this.getNews.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    const setState = this.setState.bind(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "localhost/news",
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
            setState(() => data);
        },
    });
}

render(){
    let news = this.state.news;
    return(
        news.map(function(n, i){
            return <div class="news-block">
                <Link to={`/news/post/${n.id}`}><h5>{n.theme}</h5></Link>
                <small>
                    <Link to={`/user/${n.author}`}>
                        {n.author}
                    </Link>, {n.date_of_create}
                </small>
                <p>{n.about}</p>
            </div>;
        })
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Try with this: `const setState = this.setState.bind(this); `